# How to specify which test to run (by label) using ctest with Catch2 framework?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, ctest, catch2

Catch2 can add label to each test case,e.g

testf.cpp:

```
TEST_CASE("test function","[part-1]")
```

Then using the command line, we can specify only to run part-1

```
./testf [part-1]
```

So my question is how to achieve the same effect when using ctest. I know ctest may have its own way to label the test cases. But is it possible to just utilize the catch2 label?

I've tried

```
ctest -C [part-1]
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You use [`-L <regex>` or `--label-regex <regex>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#cmdoption-ctest-L) to specify label regexes to match. Ex. for what you showed, `ctest -L '\[part-1\]'`. See also [`-E <regex>, --exclude-regex <regex>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#cmdoption-ctest-E)  ("*This option tells CTest to NOT run the tests whose names match the given regular expression.*") and [`-LE <regex>, --label-exclude <regex>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#cmdoption-ctest-LE) ("*This option tells CTest to NOT run the tests whose labels match the given regular expression.*") and [the label matching docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#label-matching).